# marker wont appear in google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                lati=51;
                longi=9;
                var latiLongi = new google.maps.LatLng(lati,longi);
                var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({position: latiLongi,icon: imon,title:"51,9"}); 
              });
```

I have a marker on the map already. On clicking it this marker should display at 51,9. But it doesnt. I am using markerclusterer also in my code, but not with this 51,9 position new marker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to associate the map with your marker1. Something like:

```
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latiLongi,
    icon: imon,
    title:"51,9", 
    map:yourmap
});
```